# How do I get R files to start?

Tags: r, windows, file, startup

I am learning how to use R from the following video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_V8eKsto3Ug

After downloading R he asked us to download 'R01_Intro_Files'and after I downloaded the zip folder provided in the description in the video and unzipped the folder the files would not open on my computer. Someone please instruct me on how to start these files.

Comment: That's a 2 hours video, when in the video does he say that? Also, try starting RStudio (it's a GUI, not R itself) (or RGui , since you're on Windows) and open one of the files in the zip with a `.R` extension, if any. Or are they data files?

Comment: He says it at 4:03 minutes. Also, I do have Gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If double-clicking R file does not open that file, you can simple open that from a GUI menu.

### RGui

If you have RGui, go to `File -> Open script...`:

[image: RGui open script]

### RStudio

And if you have RStudio, choose `File -> Open file...`:

[image: RStudio open file]